# Hibernate - mapping an attribute OneToMany. (like OrderLine) Not association

Tags: java, jpa

I'm strugling with JPA. I tried several things but I can't figure out the right way to put the annotations.
What is want is like an Order/OrderLine relationship.

Thus:

- Order( PK=orderId, fields=[...])
- OrderLine (Pk1=orderId,Pk2=orderLineId, fields=[...])

Obviously, OrderLine.orderId refers to the 'Order' table.

What I functionally want to do is at least:

- retrieve the Order with and without all orderlines. It should have a Set
- retrieve an orderline by full PK, but without the associated Order.
- retrieve a list of orderlines by orderId.

I only want these 2 tables and classes. nothing more nothing less.
I tried several things. Can anybody help me out with putting in the right annotations and members on these two classes?

Edit: what i've done so far.
Note that in this real example User=Order and UserRun=OrderLine. So, i am not interested in a seperate 'Run'-entity. Merely a UserRun as described by the Orderline.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_runs")
public class UserRun {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRunKey id;

    public UserRun(){};

    public UserRun(String userName, String runUuid) {
        this.id = new UserRunKey(userName, runUuid);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.id.getUserName();
    }
    public String getRunUuid() {
        return this.id.getRunUuid();
    }
}

@Embeddable
class UserRunKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "run_uuid")
    private String runUuid;

    public UserRunKey(){};

    public UserRunKey(String userName, String runUuid) {
        this.runUuid = runUuid;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getRunUuid() {
        return runUuid;
    }

}
```

This created a userruns/orderline table with the PK in the wrong way:
create table user_runs (run_uuid varchar(255) not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (run_uuid, username))

1. I want the primary key in reverse.
2. I want username as FK to User
3. I want a Set in my User-class.

When I do the following in my User-class:

```
@OneToMany
private Set<UserRun> userRuns;
```

It will create a 
create table user_user_runs (user_username varchar(255) not null, user_runs_run_uuid varchar(255) not null, user_runs_username varchar(255) not null, primary key (user_username, user_runs_run_uuid, user_runs_username))
And that's something I definitely don't want! Once again, I don't want a Run-object (same as nobody's interested in a Line-class, from OrderLine)

Comment: You should post what you have done so far and explain your problem with that.

Comment: edited the original post. Though, I think it makes the question more unclear. It basically should be like this: I want 2 classes: Order, OrderLine. I also want 2 tables: Order(pk=orderId), OrderLine(pk=(orderId,orderLineId)). How do I accomplish such an easy example with JPA annotations?

Comment: Everything would be much much easier if runUuid (which seems to be unique given its name, and is thus sufficient to uniquely identify a UserRun), was the primary key of the entity. You would then have a straightforward, standard OneToMany association mapped by a join column.

Comment: But that is exactly something I don't want due to performance/queries. I want pk(username,runuuid) So I can query on all userruns of a user and a specific userrun only on the PK

Comment: Also, runUuid is not unique by itself. (for a user it is, so username,runuuid is unique). However the runUuid refers to some 'Run-object'. This Run-object is persisted in some other external service. So this is actually some loosely reference to a 'Run'-obj. But again: I don't want a @Entity Run. I thought the 'OrderLine'-example would be easy to accomplish because it is such a trivial relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

The UserRun/Orderline class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_runs")
public class UserRun {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRunKey id;

    public UserRun(){};

    public UserRun(String userName, String runUuid) {
        this.id = new UserRunKey(userName, runUuid);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.id.getUserName();
    }
    public String getRunUuid() {
        return this.id.getRunUuid();
    }
}

@Embeddable
class UserRunKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "run_uuid")
    private String zrunUuid; //starts with a z, so the PK will be pk(username,run_uuid). Apparently, order in PK is determined from the variable names (alphabetic order)....

    public UserRunKey(){};

    public UserRunKey(String userName, String zrunUuid) {
        this.zrunUuid = zrunUuid;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getRunUuid() {
        return zrunUuid;
    }

}
```

In the userclass:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.userName",  fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<UserRun> userRuns;
```

Unfortunately, there are 2 downsides:

1. I see that there are 2 queries executed instead of a Join on username. One to retrieve user, and 1 to retrieve the Set...
2. I needed to alter variablenames of the PK (compound/Embeddable). It seems there is no clean way to define the PK order. (Seriously?). Fortunately, the variable name is private, and not exposed by getter.

If anybody knows a cleaner way for these 2 issues. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have to do is the following:

- Because the primary key is compound key you need an ID class, as you already did:

  ```
  @Embeddable
  class OrderLinePK implements Serializable {
      // you can use physical mapping annotations such as @Column here
      @Column(name="...")
      private Integer orderLineID;

      // This is foreign key and the physical mapping should be done
      // on the entity, and not here
      private Integer orderID;

      public OrderLinePK(){}

      // getters + setters
      // orverride equals() and hashCode() methods
  }
  ```
- Implement `OrderLine` entity

  ```
  @Entity
  public class OrderLine {
      @EmbededId private OrderLinePK id;

      @Mapsid("orderID")
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", referencedColumn="ID")
      private Order order;

      // getters + setters ....

  }
  ```
- And the `Order` entity:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Order {
      @Id
      private Integer id;

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // actually default by 1-to-n
      private Coolection<OrderLine> orderLines;

      // getters + setters ....

  }
  ```